# how to choose block size and C in adaptive threshold in opencv (cv2)

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I wanted to know what is the best possible block-size and C (Constant) for adaptiveThresholding. Also, in my case **images keeps changing**

```
th1 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 0)
```

as for now I am doing try and error which I don't think is best approach for determination and from official documentation I was not able to understand what values need to be selected.

Answer (score 0):

There is no best parameter set. Why would you have parameters at all if one particular combination would work best?

There is no rule how to pick those parameters. It always depends on your particular problem and images.

Blocksize is also limited by performance as of course the number of pixels to process greatly increases with increasing blocksize.

Comment: This is sort of a non-answer. Given a particular problem and images... how *would* one optimize blocksize and constant (even if there is no universal answer)? Or, for the same image and goal, "increasing/decreasing blocksize tends to [...]" and "increasing/decreasing the constnat tends to [...]".

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by **"images keep changing".** Could you provide the code?

If by that you mean, the original image changes, you can save your image using a different name.

In terms of best parameters, there is none and depends on some features e.g. the input image quality and also what you wish to accomplish.